# Tab animation for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css

I have a tab with four items, which are stacked on top in mobile devices. I need to animate the clicked `li` to animate to bottom. I managed to do this with some CSS animation.

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/wf0y9wbx/3/

I am not able to control the upward movement. The bottom items are not always moving up together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your original code was that you were looping over the dom elements, which were in the same order, every time a `li` was clicked.

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $('li').attr({
        style: ''
    });
    var place = $(this).attr("class");

    if (typeof place !== "undefined"){
        place = parseInt(place.replace("li-",""));
    }else{
        place = $(this).index() + 1;
    }

    $(this).css('z-index', '2').attr('class','').addClass('li-4');

    $('li').not($(this)).each(function(){
        var thisPlace = $(this).attr("class");
        if (typeof thisPlace !== "undefined"){
            thisPlace = parseInt(thisPlace.replace("li-",""));
        }else{
            thisPlace = $(this).index() + 1;
        }

        if(thisPlace > place){
            $(this).attr('class','');
            $(this).addClass('li-' + (thisPlace - 1));
        }
    });
});
```

This is not the most elegant answer, but it works. This checks for a class first and parses the number out as the variable "place", if a class doesn't exist it checks the element's index within the `ul`.

Comment: What's the use for setting the z-index to 2?

Comment: I don't know, it was in the code given in the jsfiddle so I left it figured it might be important and left it in there.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I added z-index only to bring clicked item to top.